# Using cfqueryparam with custom tag? Nesting native tags with custom tags

Tags: coldfusion, nested, cfquery, custom-tags, cfqueryparam

I basically want to allow something like:

```
<cf_datatables datasource="#someDS#">

    <cf_datatables_records>

        SELECT
            `someColumn1`,
            `someColumn2`

        FROM
            `#someDB#`.`#someT#`

        WHERE
            `someColumn1` = <cfqueryparam value="#someValue#"  cfSqlType="CF_SQL_INTEGER">

        LIMIT
            10

    </cf_datatables_records>

</cf_datatables>
```

The `cf_datatables_records` custom tag (child) is a sub-query/recordset that will be used within the `cf_datatables` custom tag (parent). This would be the SQL result when executing the above:

```
SELECT
    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *

FROM (

        SELECT
            `someColumn1`,
            `someColumn2`

        FROM
            `#someDB#`.`#someT#`

        WHERE
            `someColumn1` = <cfqueryparam value="#someValue#"  cfSqlType="CF_SQL_INTEGER">

        LIMIT
            10

) AS `base`

UNION (...)

WHERE ... GROUP BY ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT ... etc. (depends on the provided parameters)
```

Unfortunately ColdFusion parses the `cfqueryparam` tag before passing them to the custom tag resulting in:

`Context validation error for tag cfqueryparam. The tag must be nested inside a cfquery tag.`

It does work if I omit `cfqueryparam` but that's obviously not acceptable. So is parsing the queryparam.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Not sure why these sort of custom tags exist. It's like a rewrite of cfquery which works very well. I don't think you can fix this unless you rewrite the datatables custom tag to include cfqueryparam at the point where you finally get it into the cfquery tag. You are gaining nothing from the use of this custom tag except additional parsing overhead.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible with tags. Possibly with the cfscript version of cfquery. However, I am not sure I see the value of this either. What is the use case? Side note, depending on the source of `#foo2#` and `#foo3#` you could still be exposing the db to sql injection.

Comment: The intend is to simplify the way the data has to be prepared. I want our junior developers to only care for the records, not the sub-selecting required for additional information such as dynamically filtering, determining possible recordcount etc.

Comment: The code I posted is generic and simply describes what I want to do a.k.a an example, so the actual thing is something more than just building two queries. A possible solution would be to pass the queries by argument, but this requires to know about the sub-select unless I'm willing to fire twice as much queries i.e. query-on-query.

Comment: A better approach might be to write stored procedure which are available to your junior developers.  That would satisfy the requirment of having to only deal with the records.

Comment: SP would be the database-wise equivalent to the "pass as argument"-way, but that would probably end up more cumbersome as filters and ordering are applied in the same query thus the sudden need to provide tons of params with the SP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just found out that I can include SQL instructions inside of cfquery without dealing with the native tag issue.

```
<cfquery datasource="#someDS#">

    <!--- count possible records --->
    <cfmodule dtArguments="#dtController.params#" template="datatables-processing-pre.cfm">

        <!--- select records for the desired entity --->
        SELECT
            `someColumn1`,
            `someColumn2`

        FROM
            `#someDB#`.`#someT#`

        WHERE
            `someColumn1` = <cfqueryparam value="#someValue#"  cfSqlType="CF_SQL_INTEGER">

        LIMIT
            10

    <!--- filter, order and paginate records --->
    <cfmodule dtArguments="#dtController.params#" template="datatables-processing-post.cfm">

</cfquery>
```

The two includes complement the select dynamically.

Content of `datatables-processing-pre.cfm`:

```
SELECT
    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *

FROM (
```

Content of `datatables-processing-post.cfm`:

```
) AS 'base'

WHERE
    <cfswitch ...>
        <defaultcase>
            `someColumn3` > <cfqueryparam value="#someOtherValue#"  cfSqlType="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
        </defaultcase>
    </cfswitch>

    <cfif ...>
        AND `someColumn4` LIKE <cfqueryparam value="#anotherValue#%"  cfSqlType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">
    </cfif>

ORDER BY
    <cfswitch ...>
        ...
    </cfswitch>

...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solvable, but maybe not as easily as you might hope.

You will have to create a  tag (or some such) to replace your  tags. Each of those will have to output a string that you can use (perhaps in combination with some data that the tag makes available to its parent) to recreate the cfqueryparam tag later with some looping and string replacement in the End mode of your parent tag.

If you want to see an example of it at work, check out my cf_DMQuery and cf_DMSQL tag in the Custom tags of my Neptune framework.

https://github.com/sebtools/Neptune

You can find them in the "CustomTags" folder of the repository. The crux of the problem is solved in the convertSQLArray function in DMUdfs.cfm. It takes advantage of functionality in DataMgr.cfc to handle highly dynamic SQL code.

All in all, it can be done but expect to spend some time on it.

Since Mark Kruger (who I respect and admire) posited the idea that such tags gain you nothing but overhead, I will add that such custom tags can have real benefits. I have seen tags that include the ability to retry an entire query call (perhaps to a different database) in the case of a failure due to a database connection being down.

I have used them so that I can have complicated SQL (that includes cfqueryparams) used in multiple different queries. I get the speed benefits of performing complex logic in SQL without the cost of code duplication. It is hard to post an example of that, however, as your situation has to reach a certain level of complexity to pay off (which makes it hard to come up with a concise example).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and the living example, but this workaround - as you already noted - is not exactly what I was looking for. Having found out that CF's cfinclude/cfmodule work just the way I'm trying to get custom tags to behave, I will stick with that.

As of Mark Kruger: No offense meant, but he is basically suggesting to ignore the DRY principle here. I'm not going to repeat the same sql statements and conditional build-up in 20 different files just because I cannot use native child tags in custom tags.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just add a check to see if the value is the right type before executing your query, instead of cfqueryparam?

```
<cfif NOT IsNumeric(somevalue)>
  <cfabort>
</cfif>
```

Edit: there are type checks for integer as well:  IsValid("integer", somevalue);

Agreed, it's not better than using cfqueryparam, however it may be fine depending on the use case.

Comment: This is at least wrong on two levels:

1. ColdFusion's isNumeric accepts any numeric value (e.g. decimal) which will cause the SQL to fail on integer fields.
2. Handling strings for SQL is more than just a plain regular expression check. Escaping also depends on the SQL vendor in use.